# file missing, help with recovery

Tags: filesystem, files

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Windows 7 as dual boot. While on Ubuntu, I was using files and folders from the windows partition. I made a folder in the windows partiton, copied in it a ".docx" document from another folder, and edited that file via LibreOffice. I saved and re-edited and saved the document multiple times on ubuntu. But at one point I had to boot to windows, and I saved and closed the document, restarted and booted to windows. I tried to open the folder I made back in Ubuntu, and it gave me an error. So I went back to Ubuntu and now I don't have the folder at all. I tried recovery programs, went back to windows tried over there, also the folder is not there in windows too right now.

Could anyone help? the document is very important and I have to find a way to recover it. (I also checked if LibreOffice made any copies somewhere but couldnt find anything)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool that scans the harddisk for typical headers of the file type you are looking for:

[`TestDisk`](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), which is closely related to `photorec`.

You could also look for known words in the document on the harddisk; But you can not be sure that words occur as normal text in the file, you would need to search for them as individual words, in the right order.

I think it makes much more sense to do this search on the files that were found by `testdisk`.